# How to remove all commits made in Develop and fetch only those in origin develop?

Tags: git

I had made some updates in large scale to my develop and it was committed multiple times, but now I don't want them and I need the updates in origin develop to be in my develop?
How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html

In order to discard all local commits on this branch, to make the local branch identical to the "upstream" of this branch, simply run `git reset --hard @{u}`

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need anything from your local branch, you could:

1. Remove your local branch

   ```
   git branch -D development
   ```
2. Fetch:

   ```
   git fetch
   ```
3. Checkout the origin development

   ```
   git checkout -b development origin/development
   ```